# Import a view during installation

Tags: views

I want to import a view during the installation of Drupal.

Does anybody have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can do this by using the [Features Module](http://drupal.org/project/features)

Comment: Firstly you have to Create Feature according to your view and then you have to import that feature into  your new  profile

Answer (score 2):

You don't usually programmability import views, instead you provides default ones by implementing `hook_views_api()` (usually in `MODULE.module`) and `hook_views_default_views()` (usually in `MODULE.views_default.inc`). Your module should return an array of views object has build with the code provided by the *export views* UI:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_views_api().
 */
function MODULE_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => '3.0',
  );
}

/**
 * Implements hook_views_default_views().
 */
function MODULE_views_default_views() {
  $export = array();

  $view = new view;
  $view->name = 'foo';
  $view->description = '';
  $view->tag = 'default';
  $view->base_table = 'node';
  $view->human_name = 'Foo';

  [ ... ]

  $export['foo'] = $view;

  return $export;
}
```

The [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module can generate the code for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have drush you can probably create a drush make file that specifies your features module should be included.